# xdebug on php 7.0.6 on xamp

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm trying to install xdebug on xamp

-I've installed  php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll on C:\xampp\php\ext

-I've disabled output buffering on php.ini

```
output_buffering=Off
```

-I've copied this text on php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log="c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
; 3600 (1 hour), 36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

-I've restarted apache

But xdebug doesn't appear in phpinfo()

Comment: The Xdebug wizard is handy to get it working https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Comment: I'ts working now, but now showns a lot of warnings not shown before

Comment: What warnings do you see?